# How to trim multi-space line but keep single space lines in dart? Can anyone please suggest what should i do?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, replace, split

Am trying to trim a string which has multi-line whitespace and also a single-whitespace ... I want to only remove the multi-line whitespace which varies in different length ex. "    ", "          ",
Can anyone please help me on this and also thank you in advance

I tried trim, replaceALL method with REG(\s) pattern but they are not giving the results in want

Comment: Could you clarify on what you mean by "multi-line whitespace which varies in different length "? Your examples are just single whitespaces, right?

Comment: basically i wanted to get rid of \HSP and \n tags from string ...
Thanks for your concern... I solved it by the way using replace.all("\n", "") function

Answer (score 1):

Line breaks are encoded by special characters that are different to a regular space. Usually, they are represented by "\n", whereas a whitespace is just " ".
So for your usecase, a command like

```
modifiedString = originalString.replace("\n","")
```

will do the trick. It replaces all newlines by a 0-length string, thus removing it.

If you want to dive deep into the topic, it will also be interesting to look into the differences of "\r" and "\n".